# Function is not defined store.getState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've got some problems with the store in React Native. I configured store in my file store/index.js. I exported it and then imported in App.js. The actions from reducer are executed properly, logger shows actions in browsers debugger, but there is a problem "function is not defined store.getState(). When I type in browser console "store.getState()" I get a problem "store is not defined". I have no idea what might be wrong :/ Thanks for the help!

my file store/index.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { default as mailReducer } from './Mail';
import { default as authReducer } from './Auth';
import { navReducer } from './Navigation';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { middleware as navMiddleware } from "../navigation";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    points: mailReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
});



const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);

export default store;
```

my file App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { default as NavigationComponent } from './navigation';
import store from "./store/index.js";
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData} from "react-intl";
import messages_pl from "./formattedMessages/pl.json";
import locale_pl from 'react-intl/locale-data/pl';

import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";

addLocaleData([...locale_pl]);

global.Intl = require('intl');

const messages = {
    'pl': messages_pl,
};

const initialState = {};

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale="pl" messages={messages["pl"]} textComponent={Text}>
          <NavigationComponent  />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}
```

and dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.7.2",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0-beta.0"
  },
```

Comment: when you type in the browser console? did you put `store` on `window`?

Comment: I meant in react native debug console :) What do you mean by 'window'? :)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of you typing in the window and getting an error? I assume you're trying to access the store via `window.store.getState()` because it's the browser console and `window` is the global object. otherwise the `store` you are trying to access is not in the same closure

Comment: my main point is that nothing in your code is putting `store` on something you can access inside the console unless you are stopped on breakpoint when the module is loaded maybe

Comment: @azium Thanks for your response! :) Here you can find screenshot with my problems: https://imgur.com/bRpCyFN

Comment: type `window.store = store` somewhere in your code after declaring it. see if that fixes it

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :/ The same error :/

Comment: Why do you want to access the store from the console anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your store is set-up correctly since you're seeing the proper actions fired off, from within your components, and these actions are being handled appropriately by the reducers. I suspect the issue is with the *set-up of the `redux-devtools-extension`* which allows one to inspect the redux store from within their browser. Perhaps you could try the following steps and seeing if this resolves your issue:

1. Install the Redux Dev Tool extension for your appropriate browser:

   - [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)
   - [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reduxdevtools/)
2. Add your ***redux store to the global window object***

For example, a simple `store.js` file might look like the following:

**store.js:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Note this line:

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

which will allow you to access the store from within your browser's console window. We are leveraging the `compose` function from redux to apply the necessary middleware to our store.

For more information check out the `redux-devtools-extension` official [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) as well as this helpful [tutorial](https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29)

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should install https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger it includes tools for inspecting the store.  It is a lot more helpful than the default browser debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If u use 'redux-persists' and return {store, persistor} from ../store just try this:

```
import returnStoreAndPersistor from "../../store";

const { store } = returnStoreAndPersistor()

console.log(store.getState())
```